# Changing the nexus repository directory

Tags: nexus

when i install Nexus war into my tomcat server Nexus creating its folder etc at Win home directory. I want to redirect this to my different directory.

Meaning.. I want nexus to store its repository in user defined folder

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the environment variable PLEXUS_NEXUS_WORK to your user defined folder in your the /bin/setenv.cmd file and restart Tomcat before deploying the Nexus web application.

I don't have a Windows example handy but here is the /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh on my Linux deployment:

```
#! /bin/sh
export PLEXUS_NEXUS_WORK=/var/nexus
```

I assume that the Windows equivalent might be:

```
SET PLEXUS_NEXUS_WORK=C:\NEXUS
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work to move it to my D: drive with Tomcat7 and Nexus 2.8. I also tried using bin/setenv.bat and even added PLEXUS_NEXUS_WORK as a system-wide environment variable. I tried undeploying and redeploying the webapp. I even tried installing Tomcat on my D: drive. Nexus always created it in C:\sonatype-work which is no good for me as C: is my small but fast solid state system drive.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the PLEXUS_NEXUS_WORK environment variable didn't work for me using Tomcat 7 and Nexus 2.8. Perhaps this no longer works with newer versions of Nexus.

What did work was to change the **nexus-work** setting in **nexus.properties** file, which is in the **WEB-INF/classes** folder of the Nexus web app

Here is what my setting now looks like:

```
nexus-work=D:/sonatype-work/nexus
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the Nexus bundle installer with the embedded jetty server instead of running the Jetty war in Tomcat. While you can do that, you will not be able to upgrade to Nexus Professional easily since it is only supported with the embedded Jetty.

If you use the bundle installer the storage will be in a sibling folder to the nexus folder called sonatype-work/nexus.

Check out the free book [Repository Management with Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Since Nexus 2.8, you could set the `nexus-work` as an environment parameter for the tomcat JVM, like this :

```
JAVA_OPTS="-d64 -server -Xms128M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp  -Dnexus-work=/var/lib/nexus/work "
```

It works for me as I have the Nexus OSS as a war file into a RHEL6 tomcat6 installation.